# Cannot use uploaded list template

Tags: 2013

I created a list template including the contents of list. and uploaded it to another farm.

but I cannot see it in `add an app` page. I check that language is 1033.
I also enabled `Team Collaboration Lists` list.

is there any other setting I have to enable ?